# Is it possible to add a body to a http POST request made with the dart:io:HttpClient class?

Tags: post, dart, http-post, dart-pub

I am currently trying to make http POST requests with Digest Authentication using the Dart programming language. The only Dart http class which supports http digest authentication is the [dart:io:HttpClient](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-io/HttpClient-class.html) class.

### This is my code currently:

```
  setup() async {
    var httpclient = new HttpClient();
    httpclient.addCredentials(Uri.parse("https://example.com/pearson-rest/services/PublicPortalServiceJSON"), "Protected", new HttpClientDigestCredentials("pearson", "m0bApP5"));
    await httpclient.postUrl(Uri.parse("https://example.com/pearson-rest/services/PublicPortalServiceJSON"))
    .then((HttpClientRequest request) {
      request.headers.set("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
      request.headers.set("SOAPAction", "https://example.com:443/pearson-rest/services/PublicPortalServiceJSON#loginToPublicPortal");
      request.headers.set("Host", "example.com:443");
      request.headers.set("User-Agent", "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.5)");
      request.write("""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://publicportal.rest.powerschool.pearson.com/xsd"><soap:Body><login xmlns="http://publicportal.rest.powerschool.pearson.com/xsd"><username><![CDATA["""+ studentUsername +"""]]></username><password><![CDATA["""+ studentPassword +"""]]></password><userType>2</userType></login></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>""");
      return request.close();
    })
    .then((HttpClientResponse response) async {
      print(response.statusCode);
      print(response.headers);
      print(await response.transform(UTF8.decoder).join());
    });
  }
```

The request object doesn't seem to have a field for a body. The documentation is horrible as well, so I wasn't able to find a solution so far. I thought that the write() method would be the equivalent of a body, but it is not. How can I add a body to a HttpClient POST request? Or is there a different class that supports digest authentication as well?

Comment: Why do you think `write` doesn't work? Perhaps you want to use `add`? All other available methods are listed in https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-io/HttpClientRequest-class.html#instance-methods

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer The authentification is working and the the SOAP envelope is 100% correct, but the request results in an internal server error, indicating the envelope wasn't transferred correctly or not in the way intended. I have tested the same envelope in other languages before and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I don't know what envelop the server requires. Can you post an exact error message you get from the server?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer [The error message](https://pastebin.com/PQpdWFP8)

Comment: Dart dosn't create SOAP requests and I doubt any other language does so without explicitly doing so. I don't know about a package that would provide that for Dart. Perhaps you can run a server-side service that converts between JSON and SOAP in a language that supports SOAP

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thank you for your help so far. I am aware the Dart doesn't have SOAP support. This is why I am attempting to send SOAP requests by manually setting the headers and body. Shouldn't what I did be the equivalent of a normal SOAP response?

Comment: Sorry, didn't look close enough. Do you have a way to investigate what exactly is the difference in what the server receives when you send from Dart to ehen you send it from another language?

Answer (score 3):

Write is the correct thing to use. I took your sample code and posted it to httpbin and it included the data that I wrote back in the response:

```
postTest() async {
  const body = "This is my body";
  var httpclient = new HttpClient();
  await httpclient
      .postUrl(Uri.parse(
          "http://httpbin.org/post"))
      .then(
          (HttpClientRequest request) {
    request.headers.contentLength =
        body.length;
    request.write(body);
    return request.close();
  }).then((HttpClientResponse
          response) async {
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.headers);
    print(await response
        .transform(UTF8.decoder)
        .join());
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I now see that write() is the equivalent of a body. I however now realized what my real problem is. When I send the request, I get an "Unexpected EOF in prolog" error. Do you by any chance know the source of this error? I setup a dev server and it seems to be delivering the whole body, but when I send it to the actual server I get that error.

Comment: Afraid not - that sounds like another issue on the server side and would need some debugging. I'd suggest trying to send the request from something like Fiddler to see if you can repro there and if so debug the web app (or if it's not your code, post a more specific question about that issue).

Comment: in my case the problem was just missing this line: request.headers.contentLength =
        body.length; Thanks a lot.